# Windows 10 Memory Leak ("Proc") and ("Job")

Tags: windows-10, memory, drivers, process, memory-leaks

Intro:

I noticed that I've got a problem as when i kept the PC running for a set period of time, the RAM usage got extremely high for no reason. I found out it was a memory leak. The task manager wasn't displaying the memory consuming process as it was "**Non Paged**".

Development:

[Photo of Kernel Pool Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeJsu.png)

I used a Kernel Pool Monitoring tool and found out that 2 processes were constantly and continuously increasing in memory size. ("Proc") and ("Job"). By going into CMD to trace the drivers behind the processes using `cd C:\Windows\System32\drivers` and then `findstr /s Job *.*` I found out that the process was caused by `iaStorAC.sys` which is associated with my intel rapid technology CPU driver. I updated that moving from AHCI to RAID. That didnt solve the issue. Tracing the "Proc" process leads me nowhere as it is a windows process, meaning that the infiltrator process can be anything.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: A Registry hack is suggested at http://www.jamesandchey.net/windows-10-fix-100-disk-usage/ for high *disk* usage by iaStorAC.sys. That said, that driver reserves at least 332 MB, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-filesystem-filter-manager-or-fltmgrsys/c01d47a1-2cea-4421-84a0-96e700d82c2c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many different things but I *couldn't find a solution*.

What worked but is *less optimal* was a full **Windows Re-Install**. In the end, it was a software issue, not a hardware one. The memory leak is now gone.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a solution to this answer either, and for me a Windows Clean Install did not help my situation. For other's in the same situation as me, I would recommend viewing my question and solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1784734/non-paged-pool-proc-tag-memory-leak-in-windows-11/1788177?noredirect=1#comment2796517_1788177) (for Windows 11, however).

In short, it seems that this issue is most likely related to a display driver. In my case, an AMD graphics card driver. This was hinted at in [this old google thread](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.windowsxp.general/c/dd2VAXEnwks?pli=1).

Either need to downgrade the driver, or wait for an updated driver.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1193628)

Comment: Hi @Toto, thanks for the heads up. I thought that’s what I have done? I provided an “in short” description and the final sentence describes solutions to try. I will also be updating my solution in the other thread as my ticket with AMD evolves.

Comment: My issue was resolved with an updated AMD driver, version 23.7.2. I had also updated windows around the same time which was version 22H2, build 22621.2134. Hope this helps anyone who comes across the same issues as me.