# High Non Paged Pool?

Tags: memory

## Task Manager

I have a 4GB RAM laptop. It runs fine but 3GB is in-use, and the non-paged pool is always above 500mb. I would like to ask if this is normal. ( see picture )

[Memory according in task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axB3p.png)

## Poolmon

Ok, so I also checked poolmon for any leaks and found out that "ismc" is taking up around 300MB+. I think it is an intel driver ( Rapid Storage Technology? ). If it is really rapid storage, then i have already uninstalled it but it can still be seen in poolmon.

[Poolmon Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TbdU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have 32GB over memory, and 514MB non paged pool. Forgive me if I explain anything you already know. Your Paged memory is the data that was stored on the physical RAM, but has not been accessed for a period of time, and such gets moved into the page file. This is stored on your system boot drive, which can be adjusted by you if you wanted to. The non-paged pool is for things that RAM *cannot* move out of RAM. core system files, drivers, etc. The more processes that you have running critical to system functionality, the larger the non-page pool. I would not go messing about with programs and such in the non-page pool if I were you, at least not before creating a full backup and a system restore point or two.

EDIT

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-the-kernel-debugger-to-find-a-kernel-mode-memory-leak

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-poolmon-to-find-a-kernel-mode-memory-leak

These two links will walk you through using poolmon to determine if you have a memory leak, or not, and how to track down the offending program.

Comment: it does not really answer my question of why ismc is taking up almost 300mb. I found a similar problem as mine. (https://superuser.com/questions/1582419/windows-10-memory-leak-proc-and-job?rq=1) They did a full Windows reinstall which i would not like to do. Any thoughts?

Comment: No. I do not know exactly why ismc is taking up 300Mb. I cant find out what that process is on my end, so I do not have an answer there. Look at the allocated vs. the free bytes section of Poolmon. If the proccess is taking up vastly more bytes than it has free, then it might be a runaway program or process. However if the allocated vs. free bytes are relativly close together, then it should be working properly. It should have more bytes allocated than it has free, but within a resonable amount. 10000 or so.