# Non-paged pool Proc tag memory leak in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, memory-leaks

I have been looking for an answer to this all over the internet, but I am unable to get any concrete answers. I seem to have a non-paged pool memory leak within the `Proc` tag that is made worse by Windows fast boot as it does not clear after a shut down, only a restart. I had originally thought this due to Armoury Crate being installed, as uninstalling seemed to have slowed the leak substantially. However, I am still seeing signs of a leak. Using `poolmon`, `xperf` and WPA, I have determined it is in fact the `Proc` tag, but WPA returns `Unknown` results for the process that is consuming more and more memory. Is there another method I can use to determine the process culprit?

I used the following `xperf` command as admin in a Windows Command Prompt:

```
xperf -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+POOL -stackwalk PoolAlloc+PoolFree+PoolAllocSession+PoolFreeSession -BufferSize 2048 -MaxFile 2048 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\poolusage.etl
```

I see the following results with the "Proc" tag in WPA:

[image: WPA Proc Tag Filter]

As you can see, the tag increases over time and does not drop.
Here is a single capture of `poolmon`:

[image: Poolmon Image]

On restart, proc tag is as little as 5MB, but grows over time with fast boot enabled, as stated previously.

I can try to provide any more information necessary, including computer specifications if that information would be helpful. I am running 32 GB DDR5 RAM on Windows 11.

Edit: 
Per user HelpingHand's request, I had captured some data over 3 hours, halfway through in which I started playing a video game: [typeperf collection](https://pastebin.com/Gc5eUuLN).

However, since collecting this data, I tried a fresh install of Windows 11 (per user harrymc's original comment), but I still seem to be seeing the same issue with `Proc` and `Job` tags. Armoury Crate was not installed this time around, and I only installed my necessary drivers and programs. Using [poolmonX v3](https://github.com/zodiacon/PoolMonXv3/releases), I am still seeing only increases with these tags after a fresh install.
[image: PoolmonX V3 Legend]
[image: PoolmonX V3 Image 1]
[image: PoolmonX V3 Image 2]

I only see these tags turn green (increase), and never red (decrease). I also noticed that the `NPaged Allocs` slowly increases over time, especially for the `Proc` tag. Compared to the other systems in my household, the Allocs and Frees numbers are larger, but the Usage is smaller and will decrease over time.

I also noticed compared to other systems in my household, explorer.exe uses a large amount of the NP pool. However, I am unsure if this is related.
[image: Task Manager]

I know this is a slightly foolish question, but could this also be related to hardware? I noticed my BIOS is slightly out of date, but I am not sure what else to try to resolve this issue. I did ensure that my RAM was operating correctly using Memtest86.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 Memory Leak ("Proc") and ("Job")](https://superuser.com/questions/1582419/windows-10-memory-leak-proc-and-job)

Comment: I found this forum in my search for this problem, but I am not currently utilizing Intel Rapid storage. The `ismc` tag in the `poolmon` image is related to that process. I was hoping I could resolve this issue without fully reinstalling Windows, but I am getting closer and closer to that solution. I was hoping that there was another tool that could help me find what that `Unknown` process was?

Comment: Have you reinstalled/updated all drivers? Not that they are always the cause of such an issue, but they should be a prime suspect, and reinstalling drivers is less impactful than reinstalling the OS.

Comment: Yes, I ensured that all my drivers are up to date. I was hoping the tools would help me pinpoint which driver was the issue.

Comment: I would suggest initially restart the computer, then in an admin prompt run: `typeperf -si 60 "\memory\pool nonpaged bytes" -o C:\npp.csv`.  Leave that running for 3-6 hours or to the point where the size of NPP mem, is considerably higher than when the computer started. e.g. from 500MB to 2GB.  Maybe you can link that file.

By the way, to create a ETL, you can use: `wpr.exe -start Pool`, leave it and run: `wpr.exe -stop C:\pool.etl` but I would be first interested to graph the rate of graph know when would be the best time to capture the ETL.

Comment: I am unfortunately leaving for travel tomorrow, so not sure I can complete the next part until I return. But, I should be able to get you the file later today. I am curious though, what new information will this bring to light? Unsure how we can determine the problematic driver when using the same tools, as I was not able to figure out what `unknown` driver was.

Comment: @HelpingHand, I created a csv file, but I am unsure how to upload it here other than a file share?

Comment: can you use https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @HelpingHand, sorry for the delay. I just got back from my travels. Please find the npp at this [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/Gc5eUuLN)

Comment: Don't put the link in a comment, edit and add to question instead.

Comment: Just seeing this now, sorry. That data suggests the computer starts and NPP is around 800MB and stable. At 185 samples in (185 mins as they are every 1 min) or ~3 hours there is a spike up to ~1GB, then it's largely flat.  Is this consistent if you repeat the process? Does some activity 3 hours after boot trigger this?  If this is the case, I would run: `wpr.exe -start Pool` just prior to this "known" increase in a hope to then capture the NPP allocations. After it's gone up to 1GB, if that's the norm increase, run `wpr.exe -stop C:\pool.etl`. You want the ETL to capture the large spike.

Comment: Hey @HelpingHand, appreciate your continued support. I believe I started up a game at that point, which is consistent with the NPP increase. However, I would expect it to decrease after shutting down the game, which it does not. Even after a system shutdown (with fast boot enabled).

Comment: If you think that is the behavior that triggers the problem as you see it, I would reboot, start the typeperf command again, wait 2 mins, launch the wpr.exe command to start capturing an etl for the pool scenario.  Start the game, leave it open/play it for 2 mins.  Close the game, wait 1 minute, stop the WPR trace and quit typeperf.  This way you can view the csv as a graph as before, then analyze the etl, to see all the allocations made during the trace but are not deallocated (AIFO). I would consider the process/modules/stack allocating npp mem. With symbols it might give me context.

Comment: Hello @HelpingHand, I have updated my question above, and have since cleanly reinstalled windows. However, I still seem to be seeing the issue. I do not believe this is specifically due to playing a game. This seems to happen slowly over time with the Proc and Job tags, as I have originally described. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found an answer to my question. This `Proc` and `Job` tags increase appear to be due to my AMD graphics drivers. I found a hint to this solution within this [old google forum](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.windowsxp.general/c/dd2VAXEnwks?pli=1). I am currently in contact with AMD to report my findings.

I did a clean uninstall of the driver using [AMD's cleanup utility tool](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-601), and noticed that the `Proc` and `Job` tags decreased as normal, as can be seen in the below picture.
[image: No-AMD-Drivers-Non-Paged-Pool]

However, after reinstalling the latest driver, I was having the same issue, as can be seen from the below picture. (Note, this is right after a restart, so the `Allocs` and `Usage` is not as high as it could be).
[image: With-AMD-Drivers-Non-Paged-Pool]

I believe the only solution going forward is to wait for a driver update, or as user Ramhound stated in a below comment, revert to an older driver that doesn't produce this issue.

Comment: Instead of waiting on a new driver update that might never come or will have you waiting months, downgrade the driver instead, if multiple versions have the same behavior then you likely have not diagnosed the issue.

Comment: @Ramhound, as stated I am still in communication with an AMD tech support representative. Uninstalling the driver clearly pinpointed the problem, but I will agree I have not found a solution besides trying to downgrade like you said, or waiting for a driver update. I will update my answer as my AMD ticket progresses.

Comment: After going back and forth with AMD for some time, this issue was resolved with AMD driver 23.7.2. I had also updated Windows at this time, version: 22H2 build 22621.2134.